# Regarding my interim secret clearance denied

Tags: united-states, hiring, security-clearance

Recently I applied for a federal consulting Job. After 3 rounds of interviews I finally received an offer letter and I was excited to join. However, before I could join I needed to be given a security clearance.

Last week I received mail from the agency saying that I'm not eligible for an interim secret clearance. I don't know of any reason for my denial and they didn't provide any reason. I plan to request a report about my denial.

So I ask: Since I was denied that federal position, if I want to re-apply for the same position, how long do i need to wait? Since I was denied will I never be eligible for any federal jobs in the future, in spite of very clear track record.

Comment: You need to find out why - otherwise it is idle speculation

Comment: Not all federal jobs require a secret clearance. As far as I know, mostly DOD and some foreign affairs jobs are the ones that needs it and denial reasons under the Patriot Act can be many and you may even be denied to learn why your request has been denied. But the starting point is to get the ball rolling with getting to the bottom of why you were denied this clearance. Rest is up to that answer.

Comment: Please tag this as US if you are talking about the United States. There are a lot of states with federal governments.

Comment: @ADP: I've edited this to clean up the grammar and (hopefully) make it easier to understand. I tried to avoid changing the meaning. If I did change what you meant, or if you just don't like my edits, feel free to [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/64801/edit) the question yourself and rollback my changes or make your own

Comment: As this is just an Initial clearance  does that not mean the process is still on going this http://www.military.com/veteran-jobs/security-clearance-jobs/interim-security-clearances.html implies that you haven't been denied yet.

Comment: What did the people you spoke with about the position say? Were you dropped from consideration? Do they know the reason? I don't think your questions can really be answered by anyone other than the Company

Comment: I think you mean security clearance not secret clearance.  Your investigation will be on record so if you apply for another job with the same clearance they probably will not investigate again - they will just deny.  You can ask but they don't have to disclose why you did not pass.

Comment: @Paparazzi Security Clearance ie SC clearance in UK terms  is called Secret in the USA

Comment: Usually the reasons you are denied a clearance are not things you can fix. They aren't bad things necessarily. Some information may not be able to be verified because records have been lost, for example. I would be surprised if they told you why you were denied, because if you had bad intentions you would be able to use that information to thwart the background check.

Comment: @Pepone Not is is not.  I have held US Federal security clearance and there are several levels.  Secret is pretty high and not common for short term consulting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._security_clearance_terms

Comment: @Paparazzi, Yes secret clearance is pretty high up in the ranks but if you are going to have access to Military establishments, especially Military IT infrastructures, it is the entry level requirement. Never held a federal job/contract, neither for military, but having lived in San Diego for a while, I was getting job offers for Navy contracts, starting with the phrase "Having present secret clearance is a requirement". So it is not uncommon to be asked for it. Some companies don't even talk to you if you don't have it,because of high possibility of denial.

Comment: @MelBurslan Asked for and having are not the same.  I have held it and it is not common to have - especially consultants.   It does give you access to jobs that require it and most of those are military.  And there is a lot of base level military IT infrastructure that does not require Secret.  And you cannot just "apply" for it - there has to be a sponsored need.

Comment: Yet, the wonderful recruiter's who live **elsewhere** on the planet, do not realize this and suggest that you apply for the job descriptions with  "Having current secret clearance" on the top of the requirements list, regardless how short the contract term is. I think the OP's dilemma is originating from one of those recruiters.

Comment: @MelBurslan No, he got 3 rounds of interviews, he got investigated.  And we don't know it was secret or just a misuse of words.

Comment: You can [request a copy of your investigation](https://news.clearancejobs.com/2013/08/20/how-to-request-a-copy-of-your-security-clearance-investigation/).

Answer (score 8):

Full Disclosure: I held a clearance for close to twenty years.  I've been out of that world for about ten.  I'm a lot happier NOT having to worry about safes, combinations, paragraph markings, or what pieces of paper I can or can't leave out on my desk or paperclip together.

You asked, in the title, about an interim SECRET clearance.

Here's how I understand the process, from the last time I dealt with it, which was, admittedly, a long time ago.  THINGS MAY HAVE CHANGED.  I MAY BE MISTAKEN.  If I'm mistaken, I'm sure there is no shortage of people who will gleefully point out my mistakes while downvoting me to Perdition and gone.

You fill out the clearance paperwork, your (possibly prospective) employer sends it in.  The investigating agency takes a first look.  If they don't see anything that raises their eyebrows on the first look, and interim clearance was requested, they notify your employer that you have been granted interim clearance, while they continue the investigation.

Interim clearance is not final clearance.  The investigation for final clearance continues.  If something shows up during the investigation, final clearance may be denied, or the investigation may get a lot more detailed, intense, or take a lot longer.

If, after interim clearance was granted, the final clearance is denied, your employer will be notified, and the interim clearance will be revoked immediately.

Denial of interim clearance is not necessarily denial of clearance.  It just means that something in your paperwork raised their eyebrows, and they decided they didn't want you looking at classified information until they'd dug a little deeper, to make certain you weren't a security risk.  This can happen.  I used to know a guy whose initial SECRET clearance investigation, back before there were interim clearances, took nearly a year, when the normal interval was a few weeks.  He was finally cleared.

Now, if the job is a short-term job, if it said "interim clearance required", where they need you handling classified information immediately, and can't wait for the full clearance investigation to complete, you're out of luck.  If the job is a long-term job, and they can wait, you will sit in their "lepers colony" and do unclassified work while the investigation proceeds.  (In some companies, you will sit and do crossword puzzles, because they don't have ANY unclassified work.  Think of it as an excuse to get paid to study.)

You now know that you can't be granted interim clearance, because of SOMETHING.  You don't know what it is.  More to the point, YOU DON'T CARE.  If you knew what it was, you would STILL be required to report it on subsequent clearance applications, because falsifying it would put you in a FAR worse legal position: you would likely go to prison for submitting a falsified clearance application, when the reason for the falsification was to get interim clearance.

You also now know that there is no point in applying for jobs that are advertised as "interim clearance required", because you know that you can't qualify for interim clearance.  Assuming for the purpose of discussion that you are in fact an upstanding citizen, and not a spy, there is no reason you should not apply for long-term jobs that will require a clearance, because AT THIS TIME you have no reason to believe that full clearance will be denied.  If they ask about interim clearance, tell the truth, that interim clearance was declined, and that job needed it, so you weren't hired.

If they ask on the application whether you were ever denied for a clearance, tell the truth.  You were denied interim clearance on such-and-such date, such-and-such company, and your employer declined to proceed, because they needed someone who could be cleared immediately.

My suggestion, personally, would be for you to consider a different, unclassified career path.  Dealing with classified information is a pain in the posterior.  There is a lot of unclassified work out there, and you can do quite well even if you don't have a security clearance.

Your other strategy would be to look for a long-term job, that can afford to wait and have you do unclassified work while the clearance investigation proceeds.